# JPQL - NamedQuery Update with named parameters in SET

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I am trying to do a NamedQuery that is an update here is my query

```
@NamedQuery(name="User.updateUserCompany", query="UPDATE User u SET u.company = :company WHERE u.userId = :userId")
```

And I am error a compile error say

```
Input parameters can only be used in the WHERE clause or HAVING clause of a query.
```

How can I set what I want to update?

Thanks

Comment: As the message tells you, with the JPA spec you cannot use parameters in the UPDATE clause of a statement. Some JPA providers allow parameters to be used there (e.g DataNucleus JPA, since I do it with that), but clearly your JPA provider doesn't ... which JPA provider?

Answer (score 2):

[According to JPA 2.1 (JSR 338) specifications](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1481825167_a7026b43bcf9543e6a0838f1e4c1c6a5)

4.6.4 Input Parameters :

"Input parameters can only be used in the WHERE clause or HAVING clause of a query or as the new value for an update item in the SET clause of an update statement."

Which implementation/provider are you using?

Comment: So it will work independent of provider [**or as the new value for an update item in the SET clause of an update statement**]. I think he uses an older JPA Version. Which one?

Comment: **or as the new value for an update item in the SET clause of an update statement** is applicable since JPA 2.1.